# How sort find result by file sizes

Tags: shell, sorting, find

How can I sort by file size the results of the find command?

I trying to sort the result of this find command:

```
find ./src -type f -print0
```

I don't want the size of directories, I need the files relative paths sorted by size only.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how to do **using `find` command**:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -k 5 -n | sed 's/ \+/\t/g' | cut -f 9
```

Here is how to do **using recursive `ls` command**:

```
ls -lSR | sort -k 5 -n
```

Or, if you want to display only file names:

```
ls -lSR | sort -k 5 -n | sed 's/ \+/\t/g' | cut -f 9
```

Comment: In the first command the part after `sed` does not do anything on my machine. If I remove it, there is no difference. If I understand correctly is should only display the 9th column which is the `path/filename` but it does not work for me.
On the last command it does something but shows weird results.

Answer (score 15):

Parsing *`ls`* or variations thereof will add unnecesary complexity.

**Sorted file paths by file size:**

```
find src -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

Notes:

- Change `sort -n` to `sort -nr` to get reverse order
- The question had `-print0` but catering for file names containing newlines seem pedantic.
- The question mentioned relative paths, and changing `%p` to `%P` will get relative paths under `src/`

Comment: Very nice, but the `-type` option lacks a parameter, so should be  `find src -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -n | cut -f2-`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and leaving those notes, they were key for solving an issue I had sorting files by size @antak

Answer (score 5):

```
find -type f -exec du -sm {} \; | sort -nk1
```

Size in MiB, path is relative.

Answer (score 3):

```
find /folder -type f -exec ls -S {} +
```

WARNING! I use not `-exec ... \;`, but `-exec ... {} +`. This construction doesn't pluck every file just it was found, but it waits, while all files will be found, and then puts them to one command (this time — `ls`) as one big list of arguments.
Then `ls` is looking at files and, because key `-S`, sorts them by size, largest first.

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for an answer without using any pipe operator.

Comment: This is very efficient. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | numfmt --to=iec | sort -h
```

- `find -type f` finds all files under current directory, recursively
- `-printf '%s %p\n'`: for each file it prints file size in bytes and file name, separated by space, with newline
- `numfmt --to=iec` formats the first field (file size) in human readable format (with K, M, G suffixes) and keep the file name unchanged
- `sort -hr` sorts in numerical order all lines, understanding human readable suffixes

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Literally none of these answers actually worked.

Here's what I made.

```
#!/bin/bash
################# ls-by-min ################
##  List By Min File Size                 ##
##  Copyright (c) 2020 Theodore R. Smith  ##
##  License: MIT                          ##

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Error: You must specify a minimum file size (in MB)."
    exit 1
fi

FILE_SIZE=$1

if [ "$2" = "-r" ]; then
    MAXDEPTH=512
else
    MAXDEPTH=1
fi

find . -maxdepth ${MAXDEPTH} -type f -size "+${FILE_SIZE}M" -exec du -sm {} \; | sort -rnk1 | sed 's/^[0-9]\+\t*//g'
```

https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/blob/master/ls-by-min

You run it by doing:

```
ls-by-min 100 [-r]
```

and it will list, ordered biggest to smallest, only files that are 100 MB or bigger in the current directory. Pass in `-r` for it to be recursive.