# How to Find, Sort by Size, and Export with Bash

Tags: bash, macos, sorting

I'm attempting to use Bash to find all of the text files on my hard drive, sort them according to size, and export a CSV list of their paths.

This is similar to a few other threads on SO. Probably most closely to this: [How sort find result by file sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598205/how-sort-find-result-by-file-sizes)

But there are a few variations on the previously suggested code that I don't quite understand.

This line allows me to search by file type and export the results as path names, but I am unclear about how to combine this with the other necessary functions (namely, sorting path names by size ).

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' > ~/Desktop/sorted.csv
```

I am doing this on MacOS and I am new to Bash, so the solution so far has been difficult to ascertain.

edit:
Using bits of other code, I was able to piece this together. From what I understand, the "find" command finds all files with a txt extension and prints a full list of the file information, with path.  "sort" picks the 5th "field", which is (always?) the file size, and sorts the information accordingly.  "awk" is then used to print fields 9 through 13...which is a problem. this is printing bits and pieces of the path, potentially because each bit of the path occupies its own field at this point.

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ls -al {} \;|sort -k 5 -n| awk '{ print $9, $10, $11, $12, $13 }' > ~/Desktop/sorts/sorted.txt
```

Just to add one last addition, thanks to RobC's comments:
I would like the final CSV file to simply be a list of the sorted paths. Filesize no longer included. Ascending/Descending is not important.

Comment: benlat, welcome to SO. Can edit your question to show the community an example of how you want your resultant csv file to be formatted. Do you want filepaths be sorted in ascending or descending order by file size? Do you want the resultant `.csv` file to include both the filepath and its corresponding filesize, or just sorted filepaths only. If you do want filesize reported in the `.csv` file too, how do you want the filesize to be reported as bytes, kilobytes, or other? Including an example of the expected/desired output will greater your chance of getting a suitable solution/answer.

Comment: hello benlat, you say _"I would like the final CSV file to simply be a list of the sorted paths."_, what do you mean exactly? Do you want; **1)** Each filepath in a new row, all contained to a single column. **2)** Or, each filepath in a separate column with all filepaths contained to a single row? **3)** Or something else? ... Also, _"Filesize no longer included"_, does that mean; **4)** You _don't_ want the filesize to be printed in the `.csv` file, but you do want the filepaths to be sorted by size in ascending or descending order? Showing us an example of desired CSV formatting will help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec du -k {} + | sort -rn > ~/Desktop/sorted.csv
```

Comment: This would be a decent solution, although it's pointless to create a `.csv` with one column; I would do `find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec du -k {} + | sort -rn | tr '\t' ',' > file`.

Comment: Only partially. It seems to print the size information first, then the path (I am just looking for the path).  It also seems oddly specific to txt extension.. replacing .txt with .doc, it produces a blank file, making me think there is another problem somewhere...

Comment: @benlat If you are looking for path then you could use `awk` after that like `find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec du -k {} + | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: @Sonny - thanks for the ideas, but now this seems to produce incomplete paths (sometimes just printing the root folder and no other information) - and it still doesn't seem to handle other types of extension besides txt.  I'm new to bash, so I'm a little uncertain about what is going on..

Comment: Still at a complete loss here. Can anyone help?